# Pandas changing dates near each other

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with dates and users which looks like this-

[image: Initial Dataframe]

```
date = ['1/2/2020','1/9/2020','1/10/2020','1/17/2020','1/18/2020','1/24/2020','1/25/2020','5/17/2019','5/18/2019','5/24/2019','5/29/2019']
user =['A','B','C','B','A','A','B','C','A','A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Date":date, "User":user})
```

I am trying to find all dates that are next to each other (Jan-1 and Jan-2) and convert them to a single date so both entries would then become the lower of the two. The number of entries are over a million. This data is created from a scan results that triggers nightly and sometime flows into the other day. 
**Update-**
I wanted to consolidate the date of the scan so that I can show the visualization properly. As right now the results would have more entry on the day the scan starts but very few entries for the day where the scan overflowed. There is a primary date and time stored so I am not loosing the data. The user column is presented as it scans a file with all the usernames and the date stores the date when it was scanned.

So far I was able to read the dataframe and then sort it based on the date to have the entries one after the other.

The output should look like the following -

[image: Output]

Is there a pytonic way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What happens if you have an entry for every day? Would you really want the earliest single date applied to every row?

Comment: What if there are multiple dates next to each other (five consecutive days 1/1 - 1/5, for instance)? Does the scan itself set the date? Can you just use the date the scan begins as the date of record to prevent overflow into the next day?

Comment: can you add your ouput and explain why you added users? do you need to account for consecutive date by user?

Comment: The scan flows into the next day and is performed every 7 days or so. The reason why there are user is just so that at the end of the processing of the data I have the output that would contain the updated date and the users.

Comment: @economy- The scan sets this date to capture the date(and time not shown here). If there are 10 entries for first day and 2 entries for the second the output should show 12 entires for the first day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue to consider is the case of multiple consecutive days and how you want to handle these. The following code sets the day to the first of the consecutive days in each block:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

# prepend two dates to show multiple consecutive days "use-case"
date = ['12/31/2019','1/1/2020','1/2/2020','1/9/2020','1/10/2020','1/17/2020','1/18/2020','1/24/2020','1/25/2020','5/17/2019','5/18/2019','5/24/2019','5/29/2019']
user = ['Z','Z','A','B','C','B','A','A','B','C','A','A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Date":date, "User":user})

# first convert to datetime to allow date operations
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

# check if the the date is one day after the row before (by shifting the Date column) 
df['isConsecutive'] = (df.Date == df.Date.shift()+pd.DateOffset(1))

# get number of consecutive days in each block
df['numConsecutive'] =  df.isConsecutive.groupby((~df.isConsecutive).cumsum()).cumsum()

# convert to timedelta
df.numConsecutive = df.numConsecutive.apply(lambda x: timedelta(days=x))

# take this as differnce to Date
df['NewDate'] =  df.Date - df.numConsecutive

print(df)
```

This returns:

```
         Date User  isConsecutive numConsecutive    NewDate
0  2019-12-31    Z          False         0 days 2019-12-31
1  2020-01-01    Z           True         1 days 2019-12-31
2  2020-01-02    A           True         2 days 2019-12-31
3  2020-01-09    B          False         0 days 2020-01-09
4  2020-01-10    C           True         1 days 2020-01-09
5  2020-01-17    B          False         0 days 2020-01-17
6  2020-01-18    A           True         1 days 2020-01-17
7  2020-01-24    A          False         0 days 2020-01-24
8  2020-01-25    B           True         1 days 2020-01-24
9  2019-05-17    C          False         0 days 2019-05-17
10 2019-05-18    A           True         1 days 2019-05-17
11 2019-05-24    A          False         0 days 2019-05-24
12 2019-05-29    B          False         0 days 2019-05-29
```